# When to use articles and when not to?

Tags: articles, signage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please use other door?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31410/please-use-other-door)
>   [Is "Stick no bills" correct English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/is-stick-no-bills-correct-english)
>   [“train approaching”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9166/train-approaching)
>   [What's with syntax in newspaper headlines?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/whats-with-syntax-in-newspaper-headlines)

Well, I know the basic rules about using articles, but this is a different case.
On pedestrian traffic lights there are signs like:

> Press button. Wait for signal.

Why aren’t there any articles before *button* and *signal* here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Arturs. I think this is too localised. It's just a road sign message, and it can include either "[nothing]" or "the", according to the writer's preference. So, there is no grammar issue here. I vote to close.

Comment: I've voted General Reference - probably most if not all languages don't always bother with fully grammatical forms in road signs, etc.

Comment: another dupe: [why do newspaper headlines use strange syntax rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done to make it concise and sound like an instruction. eg

> Break egg and put in bowl.

You assume that the article `the` is used, as in "Break the egg and put it in the bowl." In recipes, ingredients are mentioned before the instructions, so the article `the` is more appropriate.

To make the instructions concise and easy to read, this implied article is omitted.

Comment: And is it grammatically correct? Why it's not `Break an egg and put in a bowl`?

Comment: As I said, to make it concise. You assume that the article `the` is used, as in "Break the egg and put in the bowl." (in recipes, ingredients are mentioned before the instructions, so the article `the` is more appropriate). To make it concise and easy to read, this implied article is omitted.

Comment: Good analogy. Some situations simply don't call for "grammatically correct" sentences; one such situation is **giving basic instructions**, whether that's the decal  describing how to use a blow dryer, or a recipe describing how to make a soufflé.  Highway signs are another example where we don't need to write like Dickens.

Comment: I know, if I was falling out of a plane wearing a parachute not knowing what to do, I'd prefer to read "pull cord" than "reach across your chest with your right and hand and pull the cord away from your left breast".  ;o)

Comment: @asymptotically Shouldn't it be "Break the egg and put **it** in the bowl."?

Comment: That's the point. While writing instructions (especially those as important as parachute opening instructions), you want it to be concise and eliminate "obvious" words, see @Ste's comment for an example and a laugh.

Comment: I meant for the"grammatically correct" version, not the shortened one. ROFLOL +1

Comment: Oh, right, sorry :P I'll edit that. I was wondering why you had bold-ified the `it` ...