# Why is there no article in "do not block gate"

Tags: articles

I often see signs like "do not block gate" or "do not block door"
Why is there no article before the singular noun? It's confusing as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Signs, like headlines, leave out unessential words. A traffic sign might read “NO RIGHT ON RED.” Just part of the language.

Comment: Probably for the same reason a stop sign doesn't say "You Must Stop Your Vehicle Here."

Comment: Does this (and the linked questions) answer your question? [When to use articles and when not to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76823/when-to-use-articles-and-when-not-to)